# Dining table with multiple miter cuts

Tags: miter-joint

[image][image][image][image]

I am trying to recreate the dining table shown in the attached image. I have been able to figure out the general structure and recreated it in google sketchup. However, I am unable to come up with a way to recreate it with actual wood. I am able to create the leg and then attach the horizontal bar to it as in the design. But when I try to add the top to it, I can't figure out how to get all three angles to meet at a single point. Can someone help?
Edit: As suggested, I am adding the materials used. I am using 1/2" thickness veneered MDF the entire project. I am attaching the pieces together with glue + metal strips + screws and nails.

Comment: Welcome to WSE. It would be helpful to know more about your plans. What are the materials for the top and the legs. (solid wood, veneer plywood, or other materials)? How thick is the top ? Are the legs solid? How are you attaching the legs to the sides?

Comment: @Ashlar I have added the explaination as you had suggested.

Comment: This is undeniably a posh-looking table but actually it's a terrible design as a functional piece of furniture. It's also really tricky for the builder to actually build and assemble! Anyway, in case it's not obvious the top *must* be made from plywood or another manmade board, it can't be made from solid wood and result in a stable table.

Comment: @Graphus: why can't the top be a solid piece of wood?

Comment: @jbord39 ?? Wood movement. Only 1/8" expansion and the mitres will open up somewhere, or if they're reinforced so well they can't split the top will bow. Same amount of contraction and the top will come away from one side or split down the middle. Obviously with most wood, even if QS, the expected movement would greatly exceed 1/8".

Comment: So everyone suggests that I don't try to create this design in the first place?

I have seen this table at a local showroom and I am trying to recreate it. It has been there for a while (at least 6 months) with no visible signs of problems. 

Lastly, the material being used is veneered MDF, not solid wood. Should I expect as much movement with MDF?

Comment: You should expect no movement with MDF, at least not enough to cause a problem (it's why the original is built from it). As to whether you should go ahead with trying to recreate it, obviously that's up to you. But I think you should be very realistic about whether you *can*. Do you have the equipment necessary to cut all the compound mitres accurately enough? (They have to be *perfect* or they won't work.) Assuming yes do you have the knowledge and the number and size of clamps required to be able to glue it all together?

Comment: Are you sure that the legs are really sloped at the top as in your diagram?  It seems to me it would be more stable if they were square *almost* to the top, with the miters on the tabletop creating the illusion that there's only a simple triangle plane of contact.

Answer (score 1):

Cool table.  Veneer over MDF is good for the top, but what will amount to the apron, and the legs, will require a plywood substrate. 3/4 MDF or plywood, btw.  1/2 inch material is too flimsy.

I'm guessing the factory that made the table has some kind of bracket in each of the corners.  ( Can you swing by the store and take some pics of the underside?) I'm also guessing that what looks like a thick top is actually a top with an angled apron, behind which you can hide the bracket, fasteners, and stiffeners.  I could be wrong, but I think you need to re-examine your interpretation of the engineering.

Can we post files on this site? If so, I'd really like to see your .skp -  any suggestions would be simpler to convey if I could putz with your drawing a bit.

Comment: Asking questions in Answers is discouraged here, best to use Comments if you want to ask the OP a question.